# Add between row spacing in a complex matrix

Tags: math-mode, matrices

I have the following matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\begin{bmatrix}    
\begin{vmatrix}
168 & 368 \\ 
368 & 1026 
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
26 & 368\\ 
70 & 1026
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
26 & 168\\ 
70 & 368 
\end{vmatrix}\\
\begin{vmatrix}
26 & 70\\ 
368 & 1026
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
5 & 70\\ 
70 & 1026
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
5 & 26\\ 
70 & 368
\end{vmatrix}\\ 
\begin{vmatrix}
26 & 70\\ 
168 & 368
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
5 & 70\\ 
26 & 368
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
5 & 26\\ 
26 & 168
\end{vmatrix}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
36944 & -916 & -2192 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

Each row contains a 2x2 determinant. The problem is that the vertical lines of the neighboring determinants are touching, creating the impression that this is a 3x1 matrix with three 6x2 determinants. I have experimented a little with adding `[3pt]` after the delimiting \\, but had no success. Any help will be appreciated!

By the way, I am calling LaTeX from a Markdown document, which means using extra/alternative packages is highly undesirable (albeit possible after a manual intervention during text conversion). Thanks in advance!

Comment: please edit your example to be a complete document showing the packages required (I assume amsmath, but you don't say). Otherwise we don't know what it's supposed to look like...

Comment: My apologies. I've included the full document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `[]` optional argument does not add that much space, but rather specifies a minimumn dept, but your matrices are already deep, so you need a larger value.

```
\end{vmatrix}\\[15pt]
\begin{vmatrix}
```

looks better

Answer (score 3):

The values of `\vskip` in the following solution are too big for better effect, but the idea should be clear.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\begin{bmatrix}    
\begin{vmatrix}
168 & 368 \\ 
368 & 1026 
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
26 & 368\\ 
70 & 1026
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
26 & 168\\ 
70 & 368 
\end{vmatrix}\\\noalign{\vskip12pt}
\begin{vmatrix}
26 & 70\\ 
368 & 1026
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
5 & 70\\ 
70 & 1026
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
5 & 26\\ 
70 & 368
\end{vmatrix}\\ \noalign{\vskip18pt}
\begin{vmatrix}
26 & 70\\ 
168 & 368
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
5 & 70\\ 
26 & 368
\end{vmatrix} & \begin{vmatrix}
5 & 26\\ 
26 & 168
\end{vmatrix}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
36944 & -916 & -2192 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\\[18pt]` would have the same effect

Comment: @egreg as I was just writing in my answer at the time of your comment:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  AND egreg: Certainly! But always the same solution? It would be boring. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the stretch of `bmatrix` and/or `vmatrix`, perhaps via a new environment altogether:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newenvironment{BMatrix}[1][1]
  {\begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}
  \begin{bmatrix}}
  {\end{bmatrix}\endgroup}
\newenvironment{VMatrix}[1][1]
  {\begingroup\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}
  \begin{vmatrix}}
  {\end{vmatrix}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{BMatrix}[2]
    \begin{VMatrix}
      168 &  368 \\ 368 & 1026
    \end{VMatrix} & \begin{VMatrix}
       26 &  368 \\  70 & 1026
    \end{VMatrix} & \begin{VMatrix}
       26 &  168 \\  70 &  368
    \end{VMatrix} \\
    \begin{VMatrix}
       26 &   70 \\ 368 & 1026
    \end{VMatrix} & \begin{VMatrix}
        5 &   70 \\  70 & 1026
    \end{VMatrix} & \begin{VMatrix}
        5 &   26 \\  70 &  368
    \end{VMatrix} \\
    \begin{VMatrix}
       26 &   70 \\ 168 &  368
    \end{VMatrix} & \begin{VMatrix}
        5 &   70 \\  26 &  368
    \end{VMatrix} & \begin{VMatrix}
        5 &   26 \\  26 &  168
    \end{VMatrix}
  \end{BMatrix} = 
  \begin{bmatrix}
    36944 & -916 & -2192
  \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Both `BMatrix` and `VMatrix` takes an optional argument that specifies the `\arraystretch` used (default is `1`). The outer `BMatrix` is set with an `\arraystretch` of `2`.